# Looping inside jQuery function only issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I'm having some trouble with jQuery in Meteor - I'm just trying to learn so I hope someone could help.

So when #addButton is clicked it will append the div to the .formField and each div created on click will have an unique class, eg formField[1], formField[2] etc

The trouble is when the button is clicked instead of just changing the name of the div only, the div is also added 50 times. I know how dumb it sounds as its a loop, but how would I loop only the div's class on click so each have a different name?

*My code is below:*

```
Template.form.events({
'click #addButton': function(event) {

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

$(".formField").append('<div class="formField['+i+']">.....</div>');
}

return false;
```

Comment: Don't use a loop at all. Use a counter variable defined outside the function so that it retains its value in between calls. Incidentally, the concept of "class" doesn't naturally go with "unique" - why aren't you using ids?

Comment: I feel so dumb now, ofcourse a loop wouldn't work.

I only did class in the example, you're right though about id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are doing here you don't need a loop.  You just need a variable to increment every time the button is clicked.  Take your append out of the loop and instead on click increment your variable by one then call an append.  No loop necessary.

```
var i = 0;

Template.form.events({
    'click #addButton': function(event) {
         i += 1;

         $(".formField").append('<div class="formField['+i+']">.....</div>');
    }
});

return false;
```

Comment: Yes, I feel dumb now. I dont know why I thought a loop would be correct

Comment: No problem it happens, if this helps please accept as answer.

Comment: Added code that should do it sorry I am on mobile so tabbing etc is a little off

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, (i.e. by creating a closure), click run to verify

```js
var uuid = 0;

$('#addButton').on('click', function (event) {
  uuid = uuid + 1;
  $(".formField").append('<div class="formField[' + uuid + ']">Form' + uuid + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="formField"></div>

<input type="button" value="Add New" id="addButton"></input>
```